# Performance penalties of interop'ing C# with C functions

Tags: c#, c, interop, profiling

Barring actual performance tests of my code (I'm at the design stage), what is the general consensus on interfacing C code into C#? When will it be fruitful to do so, and when would it not?

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple answer.

Most of the time, the overhead of marshaling parameters into and back from methods will be negligible, and often far lower then the processing done inside the function if it's not a trivial function. However, doing it inside a tight, performance-critical loop might violate your performance constraints.

The overhead itself largely depends on type of arguments and return values of the method. It is cheaper to marshal an integer than an array containing structures which contain many strings.

It is impossible to tell without knowing your use cases.

Comment: Well, this helps a bit with the thinking though. I will try to look for examples online, I guess, to see if I can come up with some specific thoughts. Thanks.